# Use Elastic IP for ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have set `ALB` with `fargate`, currently I can access to ALB with dns name like this

```
myapp-LoadB-FDEWFSOAQXD4-f18c75dd4249a10d.elb.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
```

However it is said this DNS could be changed.

So I want to give this the `Elastic IP`

I have experienced connection `EC2` and `Elastic IP`.

In `Elasitc IP` panel I can choose instance.

However, there is not `ALB` is listed.

How can I set `Elastic IP` to `ALB` ? or am I wrong basically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options here, depending on what kind of direction you are heading:

**If you do not like the default DNS name**

You can create a DNS record that will point to your load balancer. This means that people would be able to surf to your website by using [www.whitebear.com](http://www.whitebear.com) instead of myapp-LoadB-FDEWFSOAQXD4-f18c75dd4249a10d.elb.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com

See: [Routing traffic to an ELB load balancer - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html)

**If you really want to attach an ElasticIp to a loadbalancer**

There are some use cases where it is really needed to be able to surf to a loadbalancer using a fixed IP. You can achieve this by setting up a Global Accelerator on AWS.

With Global Accelerator, you are provided two global static public IPs that act as a fixed entry point to your application, improving availability.

More information can be found on the AWS [Global Accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/?blogs-global-accelerator.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&blogs-global-accelerator.sort-order=desc&aws-global-accelerator-wn.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&aws-global-accelerator-wn.sort-order=desc) page

Comment: Thank you for comment, I was afraid of DNS might change. but now I understood. it continues. So I will use CNAME in my domain setting

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to create a 'friendly' name for an Application Load Balancer, you can create a `CNAME` record in your Domain and point it to the DNS Name of the Load Balancer.

If you wish to point the **Apex** of your domain (eg `example.com`), you can use an *Alias* in Amazon Route 53 to point to the Application Load Balancer. (It is not normally possible to point a Domain apex to a CNAME record, so the Alias capability of Route 53 will do it for you.)

See: [Routing traffic to an ELB load balancer - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html)

Comment: Thank you for comment, At first I thought the DNS might be change, but it was wrong. I just use CNAME in my Domain for friendly name